# StackPromo: Free Q&A Advertising Service (beta)

Tags: app, website

## Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image: StackPromo Logo]

## About

StackPromo is a free SE post advertising platform. Submit your posts. Webmasters can embed the ads on their site.

#### SUBMIT YOUR POSTS HERE: https://stackpromo.appspot.com/

#### EMBED ADS ON YOUR WEBSITE:

**Banner (600x100):**

```
<iframe src="https://stackpromo.appspot.com/advert" width="600" height="100"></iframe>
```

**Square (300x300):**

```
<iframe src="https://stackpromo.appspot.com/advert" width="300" height="300"></iframe>
```

**Sidebar (200x500):**

```
<iframe src="https://stackpromo.appspot.com/advert" width="200" height="500"></iframe>
```

## License

Just regular old copyright

## Download

#### SUBMIT YOUR POSTS HERE: https://stackpromo.appspot.com/

#### EMBED ADS ON YOUR WEBSITE:

**Banner (600x100):**

```
<iframe src="https://stackpromo.appspot.com/advert" width="600" height="100"></iframe>
```

**Square (300x300):**

```
<iframe src="https://stackpromo.appspot.com/advert" width="300" height="300"></iframe>
```

**Sidebar (200x500):**

```
<iframe src="https://stackpromo.appspot.com/advert" width="200" height="500"></iframe>
```

## Platform

Web - all browsers

## Contact

https://stackapps.com/users/33872/sag

## Code

Languages: Python, HTML, CSS, JavaScript

Libraries: Stack Exchange API v2.2, Google App Engine (webapp2, ndb), Bootstrap, jQuery

## New Features Coming Soon

- Site logos in ads
- More ad sizes
- More color choices
- User profile pictures in ads
- Support for all 173 communities

Comment: Not clear to me how this site helps. Perhaps you have an actual live sample, with a real (enough) post?

Comment: 400 bad request will be fixed in v2